# How do I transfer a started game to a new phone and resume where I left off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-transfer

I want to backup and move all of my downloaded games on my old Android phone to a new Galaxy 4 Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

Many apps will be configured to automatically back themselves up with Google, and so signing into the same Google account as the old device on the new one will be sufficient.  You can see this for more details: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2819582

Other apps sync specifically with Google Play Games, or with other account services.  You should connect the games to the appropriate service on your old phone, and then sign into the same service on the new phone.

My preferred option is to root both phone and install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), which allows you to easily back up and restore any app.  It would just be a matter of copying over the backup files to the new device and using TB to restore them.

For unrooted devices, there's also [Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) which automates Android's built-in backup service to make a local backup, but it can also sync with your PC so that you don't need to do any manual copying.  I believe that this won't work for some apps that don't support this backup method.